# Firebase Messaging component is not present

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following crash with my application :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Firebase Messaging component is not
> present

This issue occurs only with minifyEnabled true

With minifyEnabled false, I do not reproduce this issue.

My project has a multi-modular structure, and firebase dependencies are declared on a specific module (not app). I tried to add them on app build.gradle but this did not solved the issue...

> ```
> api platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0")
> api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
> api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
> ```

The following solutions did not worked:

- Downgrading/upgrading the google-service plugin
- Using Firebase BOM or not.

Any help would be appreciated